# Integrable functions converge uniformly to integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

This proof is probably wrong but I can't see why.

Let X be a finite measure space.

If integrable Fn converge uniformly to F then F is integrable (lebasgue wise).

Proof: since the functions are integrable, each is infinite only on a null set, take the union of the null sets (which gives us a null set, since n is countable)  hence G(x) = sup{ |Fn(x)|} is integrable since it only equals infinity on a null set.

By the domination theorem on G the result follows.

Comment: Is equaling infinity only on a null set a sufficient condition for integrability?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen No, for example $1/x$ on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given and let $n$ be so large that for all $x\in X,$ $|F_{n}(x)-F(x)|<\varepsilon,$ the existence of which is guaranteed by uniform convergence. $F$ is the uniform limit of integrable, and therefore measurable, functions, so it is measurable. Using the triangle inequality, we have: $$\int_{X}|F(x)|\mu(\mathrm{d}x)\leq \int_{X} |F_{n}(x)|+|F_{n}(x)-F(x)|\mu(\mathrm{d}x)< \int_{X} |F_{n}(x)|\mu(\mathrm{d}x)+\varepsilon\mu(X)<+\infty,$$ since $F_{n}$ is integrable and $X$ is a finite measure space.

Comment: @Zee yes. See my comment and this answerer's follow up

Comment: You should mention that $F$ is measurable before plopping down $\int|F|.$

Comment: @zhw. Fair point. I edited my response with a very quick proof for this.

Comment: @ridethewavelet does this sequence converge uniformly to 1/x? It does not seem that way since for any n I can always go closer to x using 1/x

Comment: @Zee I regret deleting that comment. If $F_{n}(x)=1/x$ on $(1/n,1),$ $=0$ on $(0,1/n),$ then $G(x)=1/x$ on $(0,1),$ so is not integrable, but you are correct, these do not converge uniformly to $G.$ The point of that example was to show that your proof was incorrect, and one reason for that is that you failed to use the uniform convergence.

Comment: But given that the result is established now, let's consider $G(x).$ Let $\varepsilon>0$, and $n$ large enough that $|F_{m}(x)-F(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in X,$ for all $m\geq n.$ Then $G(x)\leq\max\{|F_1(x)|,\ldots,|F_{n-1}(x)|,|F(x)|+\varepsilon\},$ so $G(x)$ is integrable. Note that this is clearly using the uniform convergence in the proof, however.

Comment: @ridethewavelet thank you that was informative , so I just needed to bound G From above using uniform convergence to complete my proof?

Comment: But here, we can see that $G$ is integrable since we've already proved that $F$ is. In your proof, you haven't yet shown that $F$ is integrable, so this wouldn't work.